# Do a forward slash search but don't have vim immediately jump to the string?

Tags: search

When I do a `/someStringtoFind` in vim it immediately jumps to the closest matched string.

Almost always this is what I want it to do. Sometimes though, I want to be able to enter a string to find and not have my cursor move while I am typing the string. Then, after I have finished typing the string, I could hit enter for vim to jump to the string.

How can I do this?

Comment: `incsearch` is either on or off.

Comment: You could also try `g/`.

Comment: Then i guess I could write a map to turn incsearch on and off would what work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type `:` before searching: **`:/someStringtoFind` <kbd>Enter</kbd>**. If the match isn't at the beginning of the line, press `n` to go to the beginning of the match.

`/someStringtoFind/` is an empty ex command with the range of lines `/someStringtoFind/` (a 1-line range). The empty ex command means “jump to the end of the range”, so the command jumps to the next line containing a match for `someStringtoFind`. You can drop the final `/` if you have nothing to put afterwards.

`:/someStringtoFind` drops you to the beginning of the target line. The search is stored in the search history, so `n` brings you to the beginning of the next match, which is on the current line. There's an exception: if the match starts at the beginning of the line, then you're already at the beginning of the match, and `n` would bring you to the next match. As long as the match doesn't span lines, `$N` brings you to the beginning of the match reliably, if you don't mind the extra typing (or are writing a macro).

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the fact, that you can set the search register `@/` directly, which does not move the cursor. So simply do `:let @/='foobar'`
and the cursor position won't change. If you want to move to the match, you press <kbd>n</kbd> as usual.