# How to search & replace the word under cursor without changing position?

Tags: search, cursor-movement, cursor-motions, replace

This question is related to [Do a forward slash search but don't have vim immediately jump to the string?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/do-a-forward-slash-search-but-dont-have-vim-immediately-jump-to-the-string) but is not a dup.

I recently updated my Linux box (clicked on the "install updates" button in my Fedora distro' gui), and it has definitely changed `Vim`'s behavior:

In Normal Mode, I used to perform the following keystroke sequence to replace all instances of the entire word under my cursor: `:`, `%`, `s`,`/`,`\`,`<`,`Ctrl-r`,`Ctrl-w`,`\`,`>`,`/`,*replacement*,`/`,`g`

Post-update, things have changed such that after the first `/` in that sequence, `vim` immediately moves the cursor and starts searching. This effectively kills my ability to use the `Ctrl-r`,`Ctrl-w` sequence to insert the word *currently under the cursor*.

Based on the answer to the noted question, I tried modifying my keystroke sequence to insert a `:` before the first `/` in that sequence, but that does not work: the `Ctrl-r`,`Ctrl-w` sequence inserts some other word (not the word under the cursor).

**Is there a way to just disable this "search immediately if you type `/`" feature altogether?** (I.e. instead of having to change your key-sequence as per the noted question) **Or what can I do to restore things so that the old, noted, "replace everywhere" keystroke-sequence works again?**

```
$ vim --version                                                                                 
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct 22 2019 12:17:41)
Included patches: 1-2198                                                                       
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>                                                              
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
...
$
$ cat ~/.vimrc
execute pathogen#infect()

set backspace=indent,eol,start
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set smarttab
set cino+=(0
set statusline=
set statusline +=\[%n]    " buffer number
set statusline +=\%F      " File
set statusline +=%=%l/%L  " currentLine/totalLine
set statusline +=%4v      " virtual column
set laststatus=2
set number
set ruler                 " show the cursor position all the time
set scrolloff=7           " start scrolling when cursor is 7 lines from top/bottom
set t_Co=256
set textwidth=80
set formatoptions=croqlt  " Hard-wrap when typing exceeds <textwidth>
set hlsearch
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=0
colorscheme Base2Tone_MorningDark

" highlights
hi Search ctermfg=black ctermbg=yellow
hi LineNr ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=NONE
hi Normal ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE

" syntastic stuff
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 1
let g:syntastic_c_checkers = ['cppcheck']
let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['cppcheck']
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['flake8']
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
```

I don't really know what version of `vim` I had before the upgrade, and I'd have no idea how to go about unearthing that information now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to an upgrade to `'incsearch'`. Turning it off should do the trick.

P.S.: you could map the key stroke instead:

```
nnoremap <leader>cw :%s/<cword>/
```

But I prefer

```
nnoremap <leader>cw :let @/=expand('<cword>')<CR>cgn
```

which sets the search pattern, but doesn't highlight, and then uses the `.`-repeatable `cgn` command.

Comment: TIL: "incsearch". So bonus thank you for educating me on the term for this feature.